# Select specific element by using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to extract a specific element using linq. If this element is not in the given list, I would like to use any other element of that list.

Is there an easier way to achive this? Here is my current solution:

```
string content = String.Empty;
Text t = texts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Display == Display.Terminal);
if (t != null)
{
   content = t.Value;
}
else
{
   t = texts.FirstOrDefault();
   if (t != null)
      content = t.Value;
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: Using Asad's suggested solution I changed the code to

```
string content = (texts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Display == Display.Terminal) ?? texts.FirstOrDefault() ?? new Text()).Value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write it a bit more succintly:

```
var t = texts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Display == Display.Terminal) ?? texts.FirstOrDefault();
if ( t != null ) content = t.Value;
```

If you're using the latest C# you can even use the null propagation operator to make it just a single expression:

```
var content = (texts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Display == Display.Terminal) ?? texts.FirstOrDefault())?.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know the `??` operator. So I modified your solution for my problem. `string content = (texts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Sink == DisplaySink.Terminal) ?? texts.FirstOrDefault() ?? new Text()).Value;`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it yourself using an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T FirstOrDefaultValue<T>(
                      this IEnumerable<T> source,
                      Func<T, bool> func, T defaultValue) where T : class
    {   
        return source.FirstOrDefault(x => func(x)) ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

And consume it like this:

```
Text t = texts.FirstOrDefaultValue(x => x.Display == Display.Terminal, x.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to do but you can try something like this:

```
Text t = texts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Display == Display.Terminal) ?? texts.FirstOrDefault();
string content = t != null ? t.Value : String.Empty;
```

Comment: ok, maybe there needs to be one more hint. it is not guaranteed, that the list of texts is not empty. in this case this code would produce an nullpointer exception. am i right?